# elasticsearch custom tokenizer don't split time by ":"

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

for example, I have log like this:

```
11:22:33 user:abc&game:cde
```

if I use the standard tokenizer, this log will be split to :

```
 11  22   33  user  abc  game  cde
```

but 11:22:33 means time, I don't want to split it, I want to use custom tokenizer to split it to:

```
11:22:33  user abc  game  cde
```

so, how should I set the tokenizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pattern tokenizer in order to achieve that.

A tokenizer of type `pattern` that can flexibly separate text into terms via a regular expression

Read more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html